# Is it possible to get the result of the method listAllUsers(NextPageToken) sorted by email or last signIn?

Tags: firebase, api, authentication

By default, firebase auth method listAllUsers(nextPageToken) returns the maximum result of 1000 documents sorted alphabetical by id. Is it possible to get results sorted by email, created, or signedIn?